# Refused to apply style from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enable

Tags: html, css

I am doing simple coding using html and css, but I come across a strange problem I have not seen before. It says "Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5501/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled." "

Look at the pictures. Hope you can help me :)

[image]

[image]

Need help to get further

Comment: And I have attempts to change the href tag to schr. It removes the error, but still doesn't show anything in my live server

Comment: Have you tried adding `type="text/css"`?

Comment: @Geshode Yeah. Doesn't seems to work. I was just for fun watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYRda7UtuhA and tried copying it